# Pivot a table using a stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, amazon-redshift

So I'm trying to pivot a table using a stored procedure in Redshift. The issue is that the result set is dynamic. That means that we'd need to be able to dynamically pivot the table below. This is what I am trying to pivot:

```
| object_uid | field    |  value   |
|------------|----------|----------|
| post:1     | field_1_a| test     |
| post:2     | field_2_a| turtle   |
| post:2     | field_2_b| frog     |
| post:3     | field_3_a| mountain |
| ......     |   .....  | ......   |
|------------|----------|----------|
```

This would be pivoted into the following:

```
| object_uid | field_1_a| field_2_a| field_2_b| field_3_a|
|------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
| post:1     | test     |          |          |          |
| post:2     |          | turtle   | frog     |          |
| post:3     |          |          |          | mountain |
| .......    |  .....   | .......  | .......  | .......  |
|------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
```

Essentially I am trying to construct a chained string of column names (the `field_*` columns) via `SELECT LISTAGG` statement in the subquery, and trying to interpolate that statement's output in the `CREATE TABLE` sql statement. Then once the `CREATE TABLE` sql statement is constructed, the sql statement gets executed via the `EXECUTE` command.

However, This is not behaving as expected. I am a relative newcomer to Redshift, so I apologize in advance if this is a terrible way to go about pivoting a table from a tall one to a wide one. This is the code that I have so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_proc (
    tmp_name INOUT varchar(256)
) AS $$
DECLARE
    sql VARCHAR(MAX) := '';
BEGIN
    WITH pivot_output AS (
        SELECT LISTAGG(temp.output, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY temp.output) AS metadata FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                'MAX(IF(cm.metadata = ''' || metadata || ''',cm.field_value,NULL)) AS ' || QUOTE_LITERAL(metadata)
            AS output
            FROM "content_metadata" cm
            WHERE cm."source_uid_type" = 'post'
        ) AS temp
    );

    sql = 'CREATE TABLE ' || tmp_name || ' AS SELECT cm.object_uid, ' || pivot_output.metadata || ' FROM content_metadata cm GROUP BY cm.object_uid';
    EXECUTE sql;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CALL my_proc ('output_table');
```

I get the following error when trying to execute the above:

> The database reported a syntax error: Amazon Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "$1";

A little bit stumped by the error. Does anyone have any clues / suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I added a working example of emulating the PIVOT FOR syntax in our GitHub repo "Amazon Redshift Utils". https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/StoredProcedures/sp_pivot_for.sql

I hope this is useful for you. Let me know if you have any issues with it.

Comment: Would you know if there is any performance loss in relation to the regular pivot function?